# The following StackOverflowError was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#b4ce7]: Stack Overflow

Tags: flutter

I think the problem is because of this code block. How can I do this. It needs to be for the class in order for the other functions I created to work. I can't use it when I add it to a separate class. Doing so gives an error.

```
final _sorubirIskeleState benimTestim = new _sorubirIskeleState();
```

sorular.dart

```
class Soru {
  late String soru;

  late String secA;
  late String secB;
  late String secC;
  late String secD;
  late String cevap;

  Soru(
      {
      required this.soru,

      required this.secA,
      required this.secB,
      required this.secC,
      required this.secD,
      required this.cevap});

}
```

sorubir.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newroce/models/sorular.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;

void main() => runApp(const sorubir());

class sorubir extends StatelessWidget {
  const sorubir({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: BackButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: Text('Güncel Çıkmış Sorular'),
        ),
        body: sorubirIskele(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class sorubirIskele extends StatefulWidget {
  sorubirIskele({super.key});

  @override
  State<sorubirIskele> createState() => _sorubirIskeleState();
}

class _sorubirIskeleState extends State<sorubirIskele> {

  final _sorubirIskeleState benimTestim = new _sorubirIskeleState();

  void siradakiSoru() {
    if (soru.length - 1 > soruIndex) {
      soruIndex++;
    } else {
      soruIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  String soruYaz() {
    return soru[soruIndex].soru;
  }

  String aYaz() {
    return soru[soruIndex].secA;
  }

  String bYaz() {
    return soru[soruIndex].secB;
  }

  String cYaz() {
    return soru[soruIndex].secC;
  }

  String dYaz() {
    return soru[soruIndex].secD;
  }

  List<Icon> d_yBilgi = [];

  void cevapKontrol(String kCevap) {
    if (soru[soruIndex].cevap == kCevap) {
      d_yBilgi.add(
        Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      d_yBilgi.add(
        Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
    siradakiSoru();
  }

  var url = Uri.parse('https://www.ehliyettestleri.com/coz/22ha2023e');
  List<Soru> soru = [];
  var soruIndex = 0;

  Future getData() async {
    const Utf8Codec utf8 = Utf8Codec();
    var res = await http.get(url);
    final body = res.body;
    final document = parser.parse(body);
    var response = document
        .getElementsByClassName('mtqscrollable')[0]
        .getElementsByClassName('items')
        .forEach((element) {
      setState(() {
        soru.add(
          Soru(
              soru: element.children[1].children[1].text.toString(),


              secA: element.children[0].children[2].children[1].children[1]
                  .children[1].text
                  .toString(),
              secB: element.children[0].children[2].children[1].children[2]
                  .children[1].text
                  .toString(),
              secC: element.children[0].children[2].children[1].children[3]
                  .children[1].text
                  .toString(),
              secD: element.children[0].children[2].children[1].children[4]
                  .children[1].text
                  .toString(),
              cevap: 'A'),
        );
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Soru ' + benimTestim.soruYaz(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      benimTestim.cevapKontrol('A');
                    }),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                            10, 0, 0, 0), // <-- had to set padding to zero
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'A) ' + benimTestim.aYaz(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                            10, 0, 0, 0), // <-- had to set padding to zero
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      benimTestim.cevapKontrol('B');
                    }),
                    child: Text(
                      'B) ' + benimTestim.bYaz(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      benimTestim.cevapKontrol('C');
                    }),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                            10, 0, 0, 0), // <-- had to set padding to zero
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'C) ' + benimTestim.cYaz(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      benimTestim.cevapKontrol('D');
                    }),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                            10, 0, 0, 0), // <-- had to set padding to zero
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'D) ' + benimTestim.dYaz(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                ' Sonuç Bilgisi',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
              ),
              Wrap(
                spacing: -7,
                runSpacing: -7,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```